# synchronized method for an object containing other objects

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

If I write a class that "extends Thread" and for each object instance for that class there is object variable of another class. for example:

```
public class MyClass extends Thread{

  private int num;
  private MyClass2 obj;
  public MyClass(int num, MyClass2 obj){
    this.num = num;
    this.obj = obj;
  }
```

inside that class I write synchronized method that uses method of MyClass2. for example:

```
  public synchronized int doSomething(){
    obj.someMethod();
  }
```

My questions are:

1)when I call method in class MyClass2 from the synchronized method, it will still be synchronized and atomic, or that when it goes out for other not synchronized method it will continue with others threads?

2)If it will stop being synchronized... and I want it to be synchronized, do I need to make "someMethod" in class "MyClass2" also be synchronized?

3)If I declare two different objects of class "MyClass" but both of them have the same "MyClass2" object, they will be synchronized if invoking the doSomething method or not?

Answer (score 2):

You can consider synchronized method as:

```
public int doSomething(){
    synchronized(this) //this is the protected object
    {
      obj.someMethod();
      //Whatever other code you my have within doSomething
    }
}
```

No two synchronized areas can run at the same time if they reference the protected object but that does not avoid that un-synchronized code uses this object.

To answer you questions:

- (Questions 1 and 2) Non synchronized methods or method without synchronized areas over the protected object (in your case `this`) won't be blocked when your synchronized method is running.
- (Question 3) No they won't, in that case you need protect `obj` since the implicit protected object of a synchronized method is `this`, that is the instance whose method is being invoked.

If `obj` reference  is used at different `MyClass` instances, you have to synchronize any access to the object:

```
public int doSomething() {
    synchronized(obj) //Now, obj is the protected object
    {
      obj.someMethod();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find my comments below.

1)when I call method in class MyClass2 from the synchronized method, it will still be synchronized and atomic, or that when it goes out for other not synchronized method it will continue with others threads?
  **No. Method in MyClass2 is not synchronized. You need to do it explicitly**

2)If it will stop being synchronized... and I want it to be synchronized, do I need to make "someMethod" in class "MyClass2" also be synchronized?

**Yes. "someMethod" should be synchronized**

3)If I declare two different objects of class "MyClass" but both of them have the same "MyClass2" object, they will be synchronized if invoking the doSomething method or not?

**Each thread get new MyClass2 object therefore same data is not shared among threads. No need to synchronized. Though "someMethod" is synchronized it make no sense because each object has it's own lock**

Run following code and examine yourself doing variations.

```
class MyClass extends Thread{

    private int num;
    private MyClass2 obj;
    public MyClass(int num, MyClass2 obj){
        this.num = num;
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public synchronized void doSomething(){
        obj.someMethod(this.num);
    }

    public void run(){
        doSomething();
    }
}

class MyClass2{
    public synchronized void someMethod(int i){
        System.out.println(i+"--"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
            System.out.print(j);    
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        MyClass2 m=new MyClass2();
        for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
            new MyClass(i,m).start();
        }
    }
}
```